# Updating Virtual Layer by PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, update, virtual-layer, query-layer, qgsvectorlayer

I want to update a virtual layer using PyQGIS by modifying the layer name in the query.

Although I have executed the following code, the virtual layer's query remains unchanged when I open the project in QGIS. I want to update the existing virtual layer without creating a new one.

Will this be possible? Is there any example I can refer to?

```py
old_layer_name = "ZDS"
new_layer_name = "QHS"

prj = QgsProject()
prj.read(file_path)

for layer in prj.mapLayers().values():
    if layer.providerType() == 'virtual':
        query = layer.source()
        query = query.replace(old_layer_name, new_layer_name)
        layer.setDataSource(query, layer.name(), 'virtual')

prj.write()
```

Comment: I do not know why, but your code works well for me. Maybe try to check where you have which type of parenthesis e.g. `'` or `"`. For example my query looks like this: `?query=SELECT * FROM 'deg_centroids' WHERE "id" > 5`. Also, try to add the instance to your project e.g. [`prj = QgsProject.instance()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#a26df6e8516ac9625901108875681803b), perhaps it can help.